# Multiple arguments in shebang lines

Tags: scripting, osx, portability, shebang

Linux only supports one argument in a shebang line:

This:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > pr_args <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh -e
printf "'%s'\n" "$@"
EOF

cat > shebang <<'EOF'
#!pr_args a b c
EOF

chmod +x pr_args shebang

./shebang A B C


rm shebang pr_args
```

prints

```
'a b c'
'./shebang'
'A'
'B'
'C'
```

Are there any Unices where I'll get

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
'./shebang'
'A'
'B'
'C'
```

? What does Mac OS X do?

Comment: probably relevant Q&A on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take a look in all the detail of the shebang mechanism use [the Mascheck page](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/)

In particular, the item about "[Splitting arguments](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#splitting)" and the table below to see the details for many different systems.

Also take a look at: "[interpreter as #! script](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#interpreter-script)" to understand that not all systems allow one shebang to call some other shebang script.

If you need/require more detail, just ask.